# python and f2py error - NameError: global name 'inputUtil" is not defined

Tags: python, import, fortran, f2py

I have compiled a fortran code in python using f2py (inputUtil.pyd).  I import this function into my main python code and I pass two characters to this function (locationAID and locationBID) from a string.

Here is the error message:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\FROM_OLD_HD\SynBio\Contact 5-23-12\contactsource_workingcopy\python\main.py", line 234, in batchExecute
    self.prepareProteins(tempList[1].replace("protA: ",""),tempList[2].replace("protAID: ",""),tempList[3].replace("protB: ",""),tempList[4].replace("protBID: ",""))
  File "C:\FROM_OLD_HD\SynBio\Contact 5-23-12\contactsource_workingcopy\python\main.py", line 668, in prepareProteins
    total = inputUtil(locationAID,locationBID)
NameError: global name 'inputUtil' is not defined
```

Here are parts of my main python code:

```
#import fortran modules
from contact import *
from inputUtil import *

....
def prepareProteins(self, locationA, locationAID, locationB, locationBID):
    self.output("Generating temporary protein files...")
    start_time = time.time()

    shutil.copyfile(locationA,"."+os.sep+"prota.pdb")
    shutil.copyfile(locationB,"."+os.sep+"protb.pdb")


    total = inputUtil(locationAID,locationBID)
...
```

Here is part the fortran code that I converted to python using f2py that shows the character passing to this function:

```
     subroutine inputUtil(chida,chidb)
c
       integer resnr,nbar,ljnbar,ljrsnr
       integer resns,nbars
       integer resnc,nbarc
       integer resnn,nbarn
c
       integer numa,numb,ns,n
c
       character*6 card,cards,cardc,cardn,ljcard
c
       character*1 alt,ljalt,chid,ljchid,code,ljcode
       character*1 alts,chids,codes
       character*1 altc,chidc,codec
       character*1 altn,chidn,coden
       character*1 chida,chidb
....
```

f2py worked great, so I do not think that is the problem.  I am just learning python - I'm an old time Fortran programmer (started back in the day of the punch card!).  So, please respond with something that an old guy can follow.

Thanks for any help.

PunchDaddy

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing functions and modules here. When you do `from inputUtil import *` and then call `inputUtil`, that is the same as calling the function `inputUtil.inputUtil`.

I ran f2py on the Fortran code you provided, with one additional line: `print*, "hello from fortran!"`. I also had to remove the C comment lines, presumably since I used `.f90`. Here is the command I used:

```
python "c:\python27\scripts\f2py.py" -c --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32 -lmsvcr71 -m inputUtil inputUtil.f90
```

Now I get should a python module called inputUtil. Let's try that. Simple Python:

```
import inputUtil
inputUtil.inputUtil('A', 'B')
```

From this I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inputUtil'
```

So what's going on? Let's look at the module:

```
print dir(inputUtil)
```

This returns:

```
['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', 'inpututil']
```

Apparently the capital U in inputUtil has been converted to lowercase. Let's call the function with the name in lowercase:

```
inputUtil.inpututil('A', 'B')
```

Now it prints:

```
hello from fortran!
```

Success!

Looks like it might be an issue/feature of f2py to translate the function names to lower case. I've never run into it since I use lower case names in general.

For future reference, I'd also recommend putting the Fortran in a module and adding `intent` statements to your subroutine arguments. This will make it easier to pass variables between f2py modules and Python. Wrap in a module like so:

```
module inpututils

contains

subroutine foo(a, b)
...code here...
end subroutine

end module
```

Then you import all subroutines from the module with `use inpututils` at the top of a subroutine in another file (before `implicit none`).

Comment: No problem! Please consider accepting the answer (click the tick mark next to the down arrow) if it solved your problem.